# Determinant of a symmetric matrix of order $2018$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find out the determinant of the following matrix :
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}1^{2016} & 2^{2016} & ... & 2018^{2016}\\2^{2016} & 3^{2016} & ... & 2019^{2016}\\.. & .. & ... & ..\\2018^{2016} & 2019^{2016} & ... & 4035^{2016}\end{bmatrix}$$

Through examples of order $2\times 2$ as $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}1^0 & 2^0\\2^0 & 3^0\end{bmatrix}$ and $4\times 4$ as $\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}1^2 & 2^2 & 3^2 & 4^2\\2^2 & 3^2 & 4^2 & 5^2\\3^2 & 4^2 & 5^2 & 6^2\\4^2 & 5^2 & 6^2 & 7^2\end{bmatrix}$, I found that in both case the answer is  $0$. But I want to know the procedure to find such determinant.

Comment: Do you know about the "calculus of finite differences"?

Comment: Which $2 \times 2$ and $4 \times 4$ matrices did you take? Specifically, what is the relation between $2016$ and the rest of the numbers in the matrices? Because I'm sure this won't necessarily work if $2016$ is replaced by some other number. I'm asking, because I did the same thing as you did, working it our for smaller matrices, and I'm not getting zero, but my choice of exponent on each entry may not have been the same as yours.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I've just edited the question including my matrices which I've taken for example. Please have a look.

Comment: As you "know" the determinant is zero, then finding the determinant is the wrong question. The right question is to find a nonzero vector annihilated by the matrix.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Not enough. But if you give any short trick for this with the help of "Calculus of Finite Difference" ,  then I will try to read more about it.

Comment: Yes, I have understood the question and the pattern of powers now.

Comment: @S717717 the $n$th order difference of $x^{n}$ is constant [(wiki link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I know it. But can you elaborate how I can use it ?

Answer (score 2):

So, what we do is the following : The above matrix $M$, seems to be given by $M_{ij} = (i+j-1)^{2016}$.

Expanding this binomially, we get $$M_{ij} = \sum_{x =  0}^{2016} \binom {2016}x
(i-1)^{2016-x} j^{x}$$

Now, define the $2017$ column vectors $C_a$, $0 \leq a \leq 2016$, by $C_a = [1^a,2^a,...,2018^a]^T$. I claim that every column of $M_{ij}$ is spanned by these column vectors.

This happens, because given a column $M_{i}$, we can see from the above formula that:
$$
M_i = \sum_{x=0}^{2016}\left(\binom{2016}{x}(i-1)^{2016-x}\right)C_x
$$

For every $i$. I urge you to check this yourself.

This shows that $M$ has rank $2017$, since $0 \leq a \leq 2016$. However, the matrix you have given is square of dimension $2018$. It follows that it has non-trivial kernel, hence is not injective, hence has determinant zero.

Comment: But the power is fixed 2016, in your columns powers are changing

Comment: @BiswarupSaha In my column the powers are changing, but I never said that thr columns are equal to the matrix M! See, I just want 2017 vectors which span all 2018 columns of M, so it is not necessary to keep elements to the power 2016 in such  vectors, right? In particular, if you observe that the answer is correct, kindly approve. Please remove the downvote if you are convinced.

Comment: +1 thanks  u excellent answer , i was  searching  the solution of this problem  @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: @santosh Please convince mr downvote that this is right , in that case.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг this   problem was  post yesterday  in facebook group.. may  be Mr downvote  didn't understand ur answer

Comment: see my solution also @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Answer (score 2):

Suppose  $p_1, p_2...,p_n $ are polynomials  of degree $m-1 $  with atleast one has degree exactly $m-1$ . Let  us consider  a matrix $A$  whose  $(i,j)-$th matrix has  entry  $p_i(u_j)$ , where $u_1,u_2,.......,u_n$ are $ n$ distinct  number

let $p_i(x) = a_{i,1} + a_{i,2} x +.....+a_{i,m}x^{m-1} $

Now  we can easily show  that $A=\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} .......&a_{1,m}\\ . & ....... & .\\. & ....... & .\\a_{n,1} & a_{1,2} .......&a_{n,m}\end{bmatrix}\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & ..... & 1\\u_1 & u_2 & ..... & u_n\\. & .& ..... & .\\. & .& ..... & .\\u_1^{m-1} & u_2^{m-1} & .... & u_n^{m-1}\end{bmatrix}$,

This  show that in particular  if  max $deg(p_i) = m_i < n$ , (this mean , the  first matrix  is of size  $n \times m$ and$ m < n$ ) , then $rank (A) < n$  and so determinant is $0$

For the given matrix  $p_i(x) = (i-1 +x)^{2016}$ and points  are $ 1,....., 2018$. Since the matrix is of size   $2018 \times 2018$, the determinant is $0$

Comment: Up voted, this answer is nice!

Comment: thanks u @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг